# Android Lambdaj Error

Tags: android

I'm trying to filter an list item based particular condition using Lambdaj Api along with other two api's hamcrest-all.jar, cglib jar... But it shows an below error like class not found exception. But I added those libraries in build path from libs folder  of my App. Can you guys suggest me to fix the issue.

```
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ProxyArgument
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:68)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.registerNewArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:58)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:50)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:39)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on(Lambda.java:63)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.example.android_project_lambdabj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 18:07:25.791: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm getting this exact error, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @hooked82 This lambdaj jar is not working in android version..works fine in java

Comment: Yeah, i've ran into that, just wasn't sure if you or anybody else had found a fix/workaround

Comment: check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836231/lambdaj-noclassdeffounderror-on-android). It didn't help me but might solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lambda with dependencies](https://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar) instead of lambda jar.
However, you might get an initializer exception and by referring to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16528057/2139145), it won't work for Android